# accessing list elements by list index number R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop

sorry if this is a stilly question but i can't figure out how to work through a large list via loop, not passing through the entire length of the list.

I'd like to apply some functions to the first 10 list elements, different functions to the next 10, etc.

i figured a for loop could be used to grab variables and rename then rebind when it all matches, so, here's what i would have imagined working. It's just that the attempts to limit the loop to a specific portion of the X list have failed.

X (large list of 30, with different numbers of vars in each. The data is simlar but vars need to be reduced and names recoded to match, otherwise bind.rows is just a mess!)

```
for(i in length(X[1:10]) {
  W[[i]] <- X[[i]][c(2,3)]
 }

for(i in length(X[11:20]) {
  Y[[i]] <- X[[i]][c(2,3)]
}

for(i in length(X[21:30]) {
  Z[[i]] <- X[[i]][c(2,3)]
}
```

Comment: You may not need to loop. How about `W <- X[1:10]` and then just operate on W? And then so on?

Comment: thats a good idea i was thinking the only way to work with this will be to unlist everything and then join it later, this would let me part it out and still row bind. it is frustrating to not be able to figure out how to slice a list in a loop though!

Comment: `length(X[11:20])` = 10. So your second loop is `for i in 10`. Clearly not what you want. If you do `for (i in 11:20)` does that give what you want?